# Mongo roblox API wrapper issue

Tags: mongodb, lua

I'm using Roblox's Mongo API wrapper

https://devforum.roblox.com/t/rbx-to-mongo-a-mongodb-data-api-wrapper/1661288

However, I'm having some issues with it.

Here is my data source for mongo:
[My Data Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1inb.png)

I'm trying to get a table of all "tokens" in a table
[Lua code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZcwq.png)

It just returns an empty table.

Comment: Hi @Jack - it's a little bit hard to work with screenshots. But glancing through, things _look_ correct. Can you confirm that there is a document inside of a database named `"DB"` in a collection named `"col"` that has a value of `"tokens"` for it's `name` field in the database itself? I believe you should be able to browse the collections in the Atlas UI via the Data Explorer tab.

Comment: Hey @user20042973, I couldn't manage to find the data explorer tab, however I can find the data in charts. Here are pictures:
https://imgur.com/a/lVrfmRw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the additional information [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73874930/mongodb-roblox-api-wrapper-issue?noredirect=1#comment130444321_73874930), it doesn't look like you have a matching document in the database.

Currently your query is looking for a document that is similar to the following:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: "tokens"
}
```

But the document from the screenshot resembles the following instead:

```
{
    _id: 6,
    tokens: [ 1, 2, 4 ]
}
```

You can see a demonstration of that in [this Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g2bXTxaz-dY).

The changes that you need to make depend on what you are trying to do.  If you are trying to find a document that has a specific value in the `tokens` array, then you may be looking for a filter similar to `{ tokens: 4 }`.  If instead you just want to retrieve a document that has a `tokens` field, then you may be looking for a filter such as `{ tokens: { $exists: true } }`.

Comment: I want to check if a token that the user inputs is a token that is in the list of 'tokens'.
Could you give a code example of that?

Comment: Then the first syntax is what you're looking for.  Eg `{ tokens: <input value> }`